# ACF save json to custom directory not working, default acf-json used instead

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, json

I am using [Advance Custom Fields local json](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/local-json/) so I can synchronise my forms across different environments.

See my function below, with var dump outputs in comments so you can see what is going on...

```
function acf_json_absolute_path ($path) {

    /**

    var_dump($path);

    Array (
        [0] => /sites/joshmoto/subdomains/domain.com/wp-content/themes/werks/acf-json
    )

    */

    $path[0] = get_template_directory() . '/config/acf-json';

    /**

    var_dump($path);

    Array (
        [0] => /sites/joshmoto/subdomains/domain.com/wp-content/themes/werks/config/acf-json
    )

    */

    return $path;
}

add_filter('acf/settings/save_json', 'acf_json_absolute_path');
add_filter('acf/settings/load_json', 'acf_json_absolute_path');
```

But every time I save my custom fields, nothing appears in the `config/acf-json` folder.

But if I create an empty `acf-json` folder in the root of my theme, and re-save all my ACF field groups, json files are created here instead.

[image]

I don't understand why `config/acf-json` path is getting ignored and using the default `acf-json` location?

Can anyone help me understand save/load json to my `config` folder location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two filters don't have the same output. you can test that

```
add_filter('acf/json_directory', function ($path) {
    return get_template_directory() . '/config/acf-json';
});


add_filter('acf/settings/save_json', function ($path) {

    return apply_filters("acf/json_directory", NULL);

});

add_filter('acf/settings/load_json', function ($paths) {

    return [
        apply_filters("acf/json_directory", NULL)
    ];

});
```

Comment: So the `load_json` is in and array the `save_json` is not. Perfect this works nicely thank you!